# Update posts table in save_post action

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building mini-plugin, and i'm trying to update the wp_post table content of a post item.

My plugin add a input field in post edit.php page and changing the post_mime_type of the post in the database.

but since i am doing this in  add_action( 'save_post', ..) i can`t use wp_update_post() because its doing a loop.

the relevante code is here:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'member_manager_save_extras' );
function member_manager_save_extras($post_id){
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return; 

    else if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
            !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) 
        return; 

    else if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) 
        return $post_id; 

    else{
        $post = get_post($id) ; 
        $post -> post_mime_type = "sss" ; 
        wp_update_post( (array) $post ) ;   
    }
}
```

so how can i update the post_mime_type in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to achieve this would be to remove the action and re-add it again, before and after you call `wp_update_post`, respectively:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'member_manager_save_extras' );
function member_manager_save_extras($post_id){
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return; 

    else if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
            !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) 
        return; 

    else if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) 
        return $post_id; 

    else{
        $post = get_post($id) ; 
        $post -> post_mime_type = "sss" ;

        // Remove the action
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'member_manager_save_extras' );

        // Perform any update that uses the save_post hook
        wp_update_post( (array) $post ) ;

        // Add it back again
        add_action( 'save_post', 'member_manager_save_extras' ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, for learning purpose how this  remove_action works?

Comment: You've already identified the issue in your code -- due to the action you are adding to the `save_post` hook, you are entering an infinite loop (`save_post` is used within wp_update_post). remove_action removes this action from the hook, so `member_manager_save_extras` won't be called on by `save_post`

Comment: the problem is that its break the regular update, like edit the title or text.